# Enable button only if two ListViews have at least 1 item (via WPF Triggers)

Tags: c#, wpf, listview, styles

I want to enable/disable a button depending on the count of items within 2 ListView controls.

Both ListViews must have at least 1 item (each) before the button control is being enabled.

So far, all I found was a way for one ListView without triggers:

```
// ToDo: ListViewTwo must be included
<Button IsEnabled="{Binding ElementName=ListViewOne, Path=Items.Count}" />
```

Is there any way to consider ListViewToo, too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to use a `Style` with two `DataTrigger`s:

```
<Button>
    <Button.Style>
        <Style TargetType="Button">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Items.Count, ElementName=listViewOne}" Value="0">
                    <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="False" />
                </DataTrigger>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Items.Count, ElementName=listViewTwo}" Value="0">
                    <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="False" />
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </Button.Style>
</Button>
```

Comment: Or disable on `HasItems` is `False`: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol.hasitems(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: These two DataTriggers work like a charm. Thank you so much.